# Rearrange content based on window size

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I need to rearrange some content based on window/screen size.

This is how it looks when in full:

[image]

And this is what I need when screen size 768 or less:
[image]

This is my code structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 site-main-content">
            <div class="content">
                <!--Main content-->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 site-sidebar-content">
            <div class="box-1"></div>
            <div class="box-2"></div>
            <div class="box-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure how to achieve this.

**Update:** I can not use hidden property. Box 1 contains some ajax search form. If I put it above main content (on full screen) and set display none, ajax form doesn't work anymore. So I am looking for a javascript snippet to remove box 1 from it's location and load it above main content when on smaller screen.

Comment: Only flexbox could re-arrange the order of the divs BUT not while they are in two wrapping divs. (at least at the moment). You may have to restructure or use javascript.

Comment: Try to use hidden-* classes of bootstrap for more info please check below answer...

Comment: @SunilGehlot can not use hidden classes. Please check my update.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, javascript solution is the one i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have used hidden classes in my example please check and let me know...

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09asjb82/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="box-1 hidden-md hidden-lg">
        Box 1
      </div>
      <div class="mainBox">
        <div class="content">
          Main Content
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      Box 2
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
      Box 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainBox{
  background:green;
  min-height:300px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.box-1{
  background:red;
  min-height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.box-2, .box-3{
  background:#00A2E8;
  min-height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can not use hidden classes. Please check my update.